# Leading order behaviour of an infinite sum

Tags: limits, summation, asymptotics

I would like to know the leading order behaviour of

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i\left(\alpha m+\beta\sqrt{R^{2}+(x-mp)^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{R^{2}+(x-mp)^2}}$$

as $R/p\to\infty$ (first term in the asymptotic expansion is enough). It may be assumed that all variables are real-valued. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ negative?

Comment: You're correct to ask that question- I forgot to put an i in the exponential. Apologies. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may be positive or negative, but are real.

Comment: In your proposed solution, that should be just $R$ on the bottom, not $\sqrt R$.

Comment: You may well be right, in general. It was only in the case $\alpha=0$ that I played around numerically to get the $\sqrt{R}$ behaviour on the denominator. When $\alpha\neq0$ the phase variations introduced on the numerator may well lead to a faster $1/R$ decay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work out the answer using the stationary phase method and I've checked it numerically in Mathematica. For interest, it is
$$
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i\left(\alpha m+k\sqrt{R^{2}+(x-mp)^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{R^{2}+(x-mp)^{2}}}\sim\begin{cases}\frac{2^{1/2}\pi^{1/2}e^{i\pi/4}}{p^{1/2}R^{1/2}}\sum_{m=\lceil\frac{-kp-\alpha}{2\pi}\rceil}^{\lfloor\frac{kp-\alpha}{2\pi}\rfloor}\frac{e^{i\left(\frac{(\alpha+2\pi m)x+R\sqrt{k^{2}p^{2}-(\alpha+2\pi m)^{2}}}{p}\right)}}{(k^{2}p^{2}-(\alpha+2\pi m)^{2})^{1/4}},\space-kp<\alpha<kp\\\frac{2^{1/2}\pi^{1/2}e^{\frac{i\alpha x-R\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-k^{2}p^{2}}}{p}}}{p^{1/2}R^{1/2}(\alpha^{2}-k^{2}p^{2})^{1/4}},\space|\alpha|>kp\end{cases}
$$
There is at least one propagating mode in the first case whereas there are only evanescent modes in the second case (where only the slowest decaying evanescent mode need be included).